# PowerShell Scripting Help - Get-ACL from existing CSV file then append to new CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file named "C:\testing\blah.csv" in this format:

```
"Agent Name","Agent Type","File Name","Location","Added (GMT)","Created (GMT)","Last Modified (GMT)","File Size (Bytes)","File Size","Extension","Incident Type","Flagged","Ignored","Location + File Name"
"Server","file","blah5.txt","\\127.0.0.1\c$\temp","10/8/2020 21:13","10/8/2020 19:33","10/8/2020 16:26","10723331","10.23 (MB)","txt","ssn_medium_data_discover","FALSE","FALSE","\\127.0.0.1\c$\temp\blah5.txt"
```

I want to run the Powershell command "get-acl" on the "Location + File Name" column in the blah.csv file and have it output to a new CSV with Owner and AccessToString as new columns.  So far, I have not had much luck - here is my code:

```
$file2 = import-csv -path "C:\testing\blah.csv"

ForEach ($file in $file2) {
   get-acl -path $file."Location + File Name" | Select-Object Owner,AccessToString 
    }
```

Can you guide me in the right direction?  The end result should have all the columns in the original csv with two new columns (Owner, AccessToString) that are populated with values from get-acl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Import-Csv` cmdlet , you get an array of PSCutomObject, so it is easy to add some properties on them, and then re-export to a new csv :

```
$file2 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\testing\blah.csv"

ForEach ($file in $file2) {
   $infoSec = Get-Acl -Path $file."Location + File Name" | Select-Object Owner, AccessToString 
   $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner" -Value $infoSec.Owner
   $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccessToString" -Value $infoSec.AccessToString
   $file | Export-Csv -Path C:\testing\newBlah.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

But, if you can, you should avoid to use property names with spaces, like this :

```
"AgentName","AgentType","FileName","Location","AddedGMT","CreatedGMT","ModifiedGMT","FileSizeBytes","FileSize","Extension","IncidentType","Flagged","Ignored","FullName"
```

so you can then replace the `Get-Acl` line with :

```
$infoSec = Get-Acl -Path $file.FullName | Select-Object Owner, AccessToString
```